# 'server error please contact administrator' when i try to run python manage.py runserver

Tags: python, django

When I run `python manage.py runserver`, I receive a server error.

I have tried for several days now to resolve this problem on my own. I have followed several tutorials to no avail. I'am a beginner, so I am new to django and python. I'm hoping that it's just something that I'm overlooking. Can anyone please help me with this? Thank you so much in advance.

Here's what I'm receiving when I run `python manage.py runserver`.

```
(Django_Tutorial) Alexanders-MBP:Django_Tutorial alexanderbodiford$ python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 14, 2020 - 11:58:56
Django version 3.0.6, using settings None
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/Users/alexanderbodiford/Django_Tutorial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 133, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/Users/alexanderbodiford/Django_Tutorial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 74, in get_response
    set_urlconf(settings.ROOT_URLCONF)
  File "/Users/alexanderbodiford/Django_Tutorial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 77, in __getattr__
    val = getattr(self._wrapped, name)
  File "/Users/alexanderbodiford/Django_Tutorial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 205, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.default_settings, name)
AttributeError: module 'django.conf.global_settings' has no attribute 'ROOT_URLCONF'
[14/May/2020 11:59:02] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/Users/alexanderbodiford/Django_Tutorial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 133, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/Users/alexanderbodiford/Django_Tutorial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 74, in get_response
    set_urlconf(settings.ROOT_URLCONF)
  File "/Users/alexanderbodiford/Django_Tutorial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 77, in __getattr__
    val = getattr(self._wrapped, name)
  File "/Users/alexanderbodiford/Django_Tutorial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 205, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.default_settings, name)
AttributeError: module 'django.conf.global_settings' has no attribute 'ROOT_URLCONF'
[14/May/2020 11:59:02] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

Comment: Run this with `DEBUG = True` in the settings, then it will show the traceback to the error.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. I received the following when i ran it.

Comment: AttributeError: module 'django.conf.global_settings' has no attribute 'ROOT_URLCONF'

Comment: go to ur settings.py and see the variable "ROOT_URLCONF" should point to ur app urls. For Example if the app name is "LoL" then "ROOT_URLCONF = 'LoL.urls' "

Comment: Hi Bhanu Tez Thank you for your reply. i tried that but i am still getting the same error.

Comment: ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_practice.urls'